# Defaulting unset values with out a if Statement

Tags: php

I think there a easier way to perform the same function but without if statements.

```
if (isset($_GET['limit']))
 {
  $limit = $_GET['limit'];
 }
else
 {
   $limit = 10;
 }
```

Comment: I think you all deserve the credit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is I'd be open to hearing it...

...But I think your best bet is just a short hand if/else statement instead. Not that it really makes any difference.

```
$limit = (isset($_GET['limit']) ? $_GET['limit'] :  10;
```

More info here - http://www.lizjamieson.co.uk/9/short-if-statement-in-php/

Comment: Gave you the credit because to gave me a helpful link..  But thank you to all who posted.

Comment: Will remember that for future questions by you :)

Answer (score 3):

short if ?

```
$limit = isset($_GET['limit']) ? $_GET['limit'] :  10;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$limit = $_GET['limit'] ?: 10;
```

This assumes PHP 5.3(?) or higher, though.

Comment: This one generates a warning if there is no limit parameter.

Comment: @akond: I should probably clarify a bit.  The `x ?: y` syntax is called the "or ternary" operator, and is functionally equivalent to `!empty(x) ? x : y`.  See the [Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) section, Example #2.  It will not throw a warning for nonexistent array keys, just like `empty()` will not.

Comment: Sorry, a notice, not a warning.
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: limit in /home/akond/tmp/php_test/isset.php on line 5
PHP Stack trace: ...

Answer (score 1):

```
$limit = isset($_GET['limit']) ? $_GET['limit'] : 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ternary comparison operator:

```
$limit = (isset($_GET['limit'])) ? $_GET['limit'] : 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write the shorter ?: expression

```
$limit = isset($_GET['limit']) ? $_GET['limit'] : 10;
```

Or better yet just write your own function

```
$limit = updateMyGetVar('limit', 10);

function updateMyGetVar($var, $default = NULL){
  if (isset($_GET[$var]))
  {
    return $_GET[$var];
  }
  else
  {
    return $default;
  }
}
```